# Why is time of contact not taken in finding rate of change of momentum in derivation of kinetic gas equation?

Tags: ideal-gas, kinetic-theory, gas

In derivation of kinetic gas equation, the time taken for rate of change of momentum is taken as 2l/u but the force is change of momentum divided by time of contact so why are we taking time for gas molecule where it is not touching the walls even?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't post your question as an image, but rewrite it. You can use MathJax to write equation (and they will look better than what you posted).

Answer (score 0):

The details of what happens during a collision between a gas atom and a wall atom are not important. Only the before and after matter.

The collisions are assumed to be elastic and sort of like a "mirror". Before, the gas atom is headed toward the wall with a certain velocity. After, it has the same speed but is headed away from the wall. That tells you the momentum change for the collision.

To get the total rate of change of momentum, you just need the rate of collisions.